# I deleted the linux partition from a dual boot configuration and now it boots into grub prompt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I deleted the linux partitions from a dual boot configuration and extended the unallocated space back to my main C drive. Now when I boot back into my PC it automatically boots into the grub prompt. What should I do? I already tried many of the solutions on this site. I can boot into windows using the chainloader command but I would like the prompt to disappear entirely

Comment: This isn't a Linux support site, and you mention no OS that is on-topic on this site (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) but you need to use an OS you want to keep, to take ownership of the computer MBR. The command to do that varies on what OS & release you are using (there is more variation for example between windows versions that Ubuntu releases in fact). This should be done before you delete the partition, but can be done afterwards using your wanted OSes recovery media (or if you boot into it).

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. As no Ubuntu is installed on the system (and no linux for that matter) this is not a problem that can be solved with Ubuntu as is therefore off-topic on this site.